# What distance measure should I use to match RIFT descriptors?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, flann

I'm currently trying to find the nearest neighbours (NNs) of a point in its feature space, using the FLANN module from PCL library.

The points that I'm trying to compare are RIFT descriptors, in the form of `pcl::Histogram<32>`, as I use 4 bins for the distance and 8 for the gradient (like in the original article).
I'm wondering what distance measure should I use, as the default one is the L2 norm, which seems kind of weak when matching points in a high dimensionnal feature space.
I use the `KdTreeMultiIndexCreator` index of FLANN to speed-up the search.

I'm bound to use the flann module as below:

```
// Useful types
typedef pcl::Histogram<32> FeatureT;
typedef flann::L2<float> DistanceT;
typedef pcl::search::FlannSearch<FeatureT, DistanceT> SearchT;
typedef typename SearchT::FlannIndexCreatorPtr CreatorPtrT;
typedef typename SearchT::KdTreeMultiIndexCreator IndexT;
typedef typename SearchT::PointRepresentationPtr RepresentationPtrT;
// Instantiate search object with 4 randomized trees and 128 checks
SearchT search (true, CreatorPtrT (new IndexT (4)));
search.setPointRepresentation (RepresentationPtrT (new DefaultFeatureRepresentation<FeatureT>));
search.setChecks (128); // The more checks the more precise the solution
// search_cloud is filled with the keypoints to match
search.setInputCloud (search_cloud);
search.nearestKSearch(point_to_match, 1, indices, distances);
```

So, what is the best distance measure available in FLANN to fit my problem ?